# SQlite reorder integer autoincrement when I delete some row

Tags: sqlite, key, auto-increment

I have a SQLite database that have a table called Bookmarks.
This table have an integer autoincrement column called Id.

Supose that I have three rows in this table, like this:

```
Id | Name
1  | Bookmark 1
2  | Bookmark 2
3  | Bookmark 3
```

If I delete the row 2, so I get this:

```
Id | Name
1  | Bookmark 1
3  | Bookmark 3
```

Anyone knows how can I reorder the Id sequence to get like this:

```
Id | Name
1  | Bookmark 1
2  | Bookmark 3
```

Just an observation: I already know how to restore the sqlite_sequence table sequence.

Comment: Why would you want to change the primary key? What is the actual problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: First of all, be sure you need it, as CL pointed it correctly. If you do, you can create a new table as a copy, with AUTOINCREMENT column regenerated on the fly: `CREATE new_table (Id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, Name TEXT); INSERT INTO new_table SELECT Name FROM old_table; DROP TABLE old_table; ALTER TABLE new_table RENAME TO old_table;`, but be aware that it will be time consuming for huge tables and also you have to got enough disk space available to perform this. This is not an operation that should be done for every row deletion.